# Goodwillie's notes from MSRI Lecture Series

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Does anyone know where I can find an electronic version of Goodwillie's (unpublished) notes from the MSRI Lecture Series in Spring, 1990? They're mentioned/cited as such in work of Dundas-McCarthy, McCarthy, Hesselholt-Madsen, etc. They should have stuff on FSP's, Algebraic K-Theory, computation of Tate Maps, Calculus, (TC maybe?). Seriously, they're cited in so much stuff, I just need to get my hands on them.

Comment: Apparently, these unpublished notes are not available online. That said, it seems to me that T. Goodwillie is a MO user. Why don't you ask him directly?

Comment: Are you certain this material is not available in his papers?   Are there any particular results you are looking for?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi will do, hadn't thought about that. Sort of new to (using) MO.

Comment: @RyanBudney Certain aspects are present in Calc III, it seems, though I've gotten some of the information on the Tate Map from an appendix in work of McCarthy (also unpublished). More than anything, I just want to see them as a whole, to see what (and how) things are presented.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing these, too. In fact, if someone can produce them and it's okay with Tom, I'd be happy to add them to the web site I have for such never-published notes.